# Anylogic Error : root.arrival: Trying to schedule an event in the past. Negative timeout: NaN

Tags: java, simulation, factory, anylogic

I have an anylogic model that connects to an MQTT network. When it receives some messages (sometimes no messages at all) it throws this error and stops the model.

```
root.arrival: Trying to schedule an event in the past. Negative timeout: NaN
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.arrival: Trying to schedule an event in the past. Negative timeout: NaN
        at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.EventOriginator.d(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.restartTo(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.jk$d.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.jk$d.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.le(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.d(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$l.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've already checked all the variables for null or negative values and they seem to be in the clear. This error seems random since it can appear at the beginning, the end or the middle of the runtime. I'm not expecting a clear solution for the issue here. But if I can know where to look for negative values that'll be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had this error when I had a timeout set to a probability distribution which was not truncated so sometimes it chose a negative value. Not sure if it's relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Your Source block `arrival` is set up in a way that it tries to create agents "in the past", likely due to how you set the model start time or what data it is fed from. If the model starts in 2023 but your data wants to create agents in 2021, this is what you get.

Change the data or the setup :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've already tried changing the time of the model. It was in 2022 first and I changed it back to 2023. But I still got the error randomly in both timelines. Any idea why?

ps: Thank you for the youtube videos. helped me a lot when I started.

Comment: No more tips, either you share more details or you try to focus in on the root cause (and then ask again) :) Impossible to help otherwise (its like asking "why is my phone gone black?" --> there can be 100 reasons if you do not share more details on the situation) :)